# PHP Fatal Error: Column 'avatar' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to develop a registration system (I am developing this site-> bottlesbeach.eu just to train my practical knowledge on the backend part) that inserts the username, email, password, session string and taken string randomly from the avatar array which will mean the name of user avatar image:

```
        $avatars = array("avatar0.png", "avatar1.png", "avatar2.png", "avatar3.png", "avatar4.png");
        $k = array_rand($avatars);
        $v = $array[$k];
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $query = "INSERT INTO users SET username = ?, email = ?, avatar = ?, password = ?, sessionid = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $v, $password, $randomString);
        $stmt->execute();
        $sub = true;
```

This is the error that is thrown when the form is submitted:

Column 'avatar' cannot be null

I don't know why I'm getting this error, maybe the '$ v' variable is null although I don't know why it should be.

[image: db table structure]

Anyone know **what caused this exception in my case**? how can i solve?

Comment: What is `$conn`? What is `$conn->query`? Maybe you want `prepare` instead?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: @inganna it keeps giving me that error there even though I entered prepare.

Comment: @Dharman I put die just for debugging purposes

Comment: Yeah, but please stop. You don't need to debug this way. If you enable automatic error reporting you will not miss any errors

Comment: @deceze I have updated my application with the exception that I get

Comment: I suggest you use the alternative syntax: `INSERT INTO users SET username = NULL, email = ?, avatar = ?, password = ?, sessionid = ?`. This is a MySQL enhancement to standard SQL, but it makes it a lot easier to match the columns to the respective placeholders.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I don't know why I'm getting these cascading errors, now I get this: The "avatar" column cannot be anything

Comment: Please edit your question above and post the actual error. I don't know how to guess what "cannot be anything" means.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Sorry, I want to write null, not nothing. Now I change the title of the question

Comment: @BillKarwin I just updated the question

Comment: *Please, please, please* always code with error_reporting(E_ALL). It will save a damned ton of time to a lot of people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error I can infer a couple of things:

1. The `avatar` column in your table is declared with the `NOT NULL` option. It will not accept NULL as input.
2. Your `$v` PHP variable is not set, or has been set to the [PHP null value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php#language.types.null.syntax). I suggest you use `error_log(print_r($v, true));` to check this.

To solve this, you must either set `$v` to a value that is not `null`, or else alter table to change your `avatar` column to permit NULLs.

Comment: this is the very thing I don't understand. The $ v variable should be null. Now I try to verify it with error_log

Comment: Did you mean to set `$v = $avatars[$k];` instead of `$v = $array[$k];`?

Comment: Yes, I got the variable name wrong, in fact it was first called array then I had to rename it to avatars but I forgot to change it there too